Dativ oder Akkusativ? Oder: Kann Schiller Deutsch?
Am Anfang stand dieser Thread aber von der Antwort bin ich in keiner Weise überzeugt. Insbesondere legt die Antwort nahe, daß auch Schiller nicht Deutsch kann:

auf dieser Bank von Stein will ich mich setzen
dem Wanderer zur kurzen Ruh bereitet
(Wilhelm Tell, 4. Aufzug, 3. Szene)

Wenn nämlich "setzen" das "sitzen", vermehrt um den perfektiven Aspekt, ist, dann müßte man sich wohin? setzen, was als Antwort einen Akkusativ erfordert:

auf diese Bank von Stein will ich mich setzen
dem Wanderer zur kurzen Ruh bereitet
(Willi Tell, redigierte Fassung)

Falls nämlich "setzen" soviel wie "hinsetzen" bedeutet, also vom stehenden in den sitzenden Zustand überzugehen, dann beschreibt das eine Bewegung und die kann man nicht an einem Ort (Dativ), sondern nur in eine Richtung (Akkusativ) durchführen.
Geht es nur mir so oder setzt das "auf ihr setzen" nicht voraus, davor über ihr geschwebt zu haben? Schließlich "legt man sich auf die Bank" und nicht "auf der Bank", um diese Analogie zu gebrauchen.
Eine Frage, von der ich glaube, daß sie - wenigstens grammatikalisch - in eine ähnliche Richtung geht, ist diese. Der Unterschied zwischen:

wir glaubten seine Aussage
wir glaubten seiner Aussage

scheint mir zu sein, daß in dem einen Fall die Aussage das Objekt ist, dem Glauben geschenkt wird und der Urheber dieses Objekts, also derjenige der es gesagt hat, nicht direkt erwähnt wird. Wir glaubten möglicherweise ihm normalerweise nicht, aber seine Aussage, die schon.
Im zweiten Fall ist "seine Aussage" der Urheber dessen, was geglaubt wird. "Seine Aussage hat gesagt ..." und wir haben es geglaubt. Man könnte versucht sein, das als Synekdoche zu interpretieren.
Falls also jemand, der in Grammatik besser bewandert ist als ich, diese Probleme aufklären könnte wäre ich dankbar.

Hätte er in seiner "Muttersprache" geschrieben, hätte er wohl "auf diesen Bank von Stein" geschrieben. Der Bank ist maskulin auf altem schwäbisch. Vielleicht ist das Ganze nur Hyperkorrektur.

Für Schiller war Hochdeutsch eine Fremdsprache. Seine Studenten in Weimar haben sich regelmäßig beschwert, dass sie ihn nicht verstehen...

Re glauben teile ich deine Interpretation. Zu setzen: Man kann einen Stein auf der Bank aufstellen. Ebenso kann man einen Stein auf der Bank stellen. Ebenso kann man einen Stein auf der Bank (ab-)setzen. Ebenso kann man sich auf der Bank setzen. Wirkt ein bisschen verquer, aber so würde ich das deuten.
Ansonsten gilt natürlich: Schiller konnte kein anständiges Detusch, Goethe konnte kein anständiges Deutsch, Thomas Mann konnte kein anständiges Deutsch. Die einzigen, die anständiges Deutsch können, sind Bastian Sick, Didi Hallervorden, und one's jeweilige:r Deutschlehrer:in.

@JonathanHerrera: you are right. especially when it comes to Bastian Sick (sic!), since he dictates only a select few stylistic errors absolutely. The Problem with Thomas Mann is not that his German is imperfect, the problem is that it is imperfect whenever used by someone who is not Thomas Mann himself. To compose like Bach is Bachs greatest achievement - but if anybody else does it it is simply plagiarism.

Eine andere Analogie ist sich auf der Bank niederlassen.

Man könnte auch auf der Bank stehen und sich dann einfach setzen.

Natürlich "konnte Schiller Deutsch" - Immerhin ist er einer unsrer Nationaldichter. Aber vielleicht nicht "deins".
Deutsch zu Schillers Zeiten war eher eine Bandbreite (und ist es zu einem gewissen Maß heute noch) als eine fest definierte Sprache. Man muß sich vorstellen, daß das, was heute die Sprache insgesamt glattschleift und standardisiert, die überregionalen Medien, das Fernsehen und das Internet, damals nicht existiert haben. Der deutsche Sprachraum war eine Konglomerat von Dialektinseln, die eigenständigen Wortschatz, Aussprache und Grammatik hatten und im Prinzip nur durch die Lutherbibel als gemeinsame Grundlage zusammengehalten wurden. Und die wurde eher als Leitfaden denn als ultimative Instanz betrachtet.
Von Schiller ist überliefert, daß er zeitlebens an seinem Dialekt festgehalten hat, seine Werke strotzen von Suevismen und seine Poesie von Reimen, die sich nur in seiner Mundart "richtig" reimen. Es gibt genug Beschwerden von seinen Weimarer Studenten, daß sie seine Vorlesungen wegen seines starken Dialekts kaum verstanden haben. Man hat ihn also schon zu Lebzeiten durchaus dafür kritisiert, es scheint ihm aber egal gewesen zu sein.
Hätte Schiller deinen Beispielsatz in seiner Mundart geschrieben, hieße er

auf der Bank von Stein will ich hinsitzen

(denn "Bank" ist wie "Butter" maskulin im Schwäbischen, und das Demonstrativpronomen "diese(r)" existiert nicht, sondern ist "d'r", das hat er wohl "verhochdeutscht", "Richtung" wird eher mit dem Nominativ beschrieben als mit dem Akkusativ [bzw. ist nicht unterscheidbar voneinander], "setzen" ist eher ungebräuchlich, man nimmt "sitzen" mit einer Richtung - Aus seiner Sicht ist alles vollkommen richtig).
Alle deine Ausführungen zur heutigen Grammatik sind soweit richtig. Mit heutigen, sehr festgelegten Grammatikregeln an einem dialektgeprägten Deutsch "herumzukritteln" das damals eher eine schwammige Angelegenheit mit viel Interpretationsspielraum war, führt allerdings zu nichts. Damals war man zufrieden, wenn der Leser verstanden hat, worum es ging und dann war es "richtig".
Um das nochmal zu verdeutlichen: Ein Schwabe sagt

Sitz auf d'r Bank und iß deine Spätzle

wenn er

setz' dich auf die Bank...

meint.

»... Immerhin ist er einer unsrer Nationaldichter ...« Nein, Deiner vielleicht, aber nicht meiner. Nicht alle Deutschsprechenden sind Deutsche. Meine Nationaldichter sind Grillparzer, Nestroy und Raimund. Und nicht Goethe, Kleist oder Schiller.

@tofro: erstens ist "unser Nationaldichter" kein Argument per se (wenn Du mir diesen kleinen Ausflug in den österreichischen Dialekt erlaubst),zweitens war zwischen der Lutherbibel (Anfang 16. Jahrhundert) und Schiller (Ende 18. Jahrhundert) schon ein bißchen Zeit vergangen und Goethe (war der eigentlich auch Nationaldichter) hat sich solche Sachen nicht erlaubt. Drittens, war die Frage im Titel in offenkundig satirisch überspitzender Form gestellt, aber ich nehme an, Jean Paul zählst Du nicht zu den Nationaldichtern, sonst wäre Dir der Gedanke an Humor nicht gänzlich fremd.

@tofro: im Übrigen, wenn der Wilhelm Tell tatsächlich schwäbische Mundart ist, wie Du insinuierst, dann ist Schiller wohl kein "deutscher Nationaldichter" sondern ein schwäbischer Mundartpoet. Ich gelobe, die nächste Frage stelle ich dann zur Grammatik von H.C. Artmann. Sei dem wie auch immer, eigentlich habe ich eine ernsthaft gemeinte Frage gestellt und brauche wahrlich nicht von Dir für das Stellen der Frage heruntergeputzt zu werden. Nationaldichter hin oder her. Nerbenbei: ich glaube sogar, Schiller ist, horribile dictu!, NICHT auf einem Marmorsockel zur Welt gekommen

@bakunin Was hier ist denn explizit österreichischer Dialekt? >>erstens ist "unser Nationaldichter" kein Argument per se <<

@infinitezero: damit war das "per se" gemeint, denn wenn es nicht im Duden steht (der in Deutschland noch über der Verfassung rangiert), dann ist es kein richtiges Deutsch und deshalb österreichischer Dialekt. Allerdings gebe ich zu, Witze verlieren ihren Charme, wenn sie nach dem Machen auch noch erklärt werden.

@bakunin "Goethe hat sich sowas nicht erlaubt": Warum reimt sich dann bei ihm "versuchend" und "Tugend" oder "neigen" und "reichen"? Zugegeben, nicht so oft wie bei Schiller (und ich kenne auch kein Gedicht von ihm in dem ein Bembel vorkommt...), aber der hessische Dialekt scheint schon durch. Und ja, ich habe den überspitzt humorigen Ton in deiner Frage zur Kenntnis genommen, und nein, ich glaube sicher nicht, dich "heruntergeputzt" zu haben (Es scheint so zu sein, dass dir das "herumkrtteln" nicht gefällt, das steht mit voller Absicht in Anführungszeichen).

Den "Witz" verstehe ich auch nach deiner Erklärung immer noch nicht. "per se" ist weder österreichischer Dialekt noch steht es nicht im Duden (dem lateinischen Wörterbuch per se) - Ich befürchte, es war gar keiner

@HubertSchölnast, dir ist schon klar dass es im Deutschen keine Unterscheidung zwischen inklusivem und exklusivem "wir" gibt?

tofro, Hubert und bakunin. Regt euch doch alle mal ein bisschen ab. Wie wärs? Worum wird hier eigentlich gestritten? Ich glaube, um Missverständnisse. Es würde mich nicht überraschen, wenn ihr in den wesentlichen Fragen eigentlich einer Meinung wärt. Irgendwie scheint eure Kommunikation aber eher im Weg zu stehen, als euch dahin zu führen. Frohe Weihnachten!

@tofro müsste es auf Schwäbisch dann nicht eher etwa „Hock di uf d Bank und iß doi Spätzle“ heißen? Und da wäre Bank auch schon feminin. Vielleicht „Hock di ufs Bänkle“ oder nur „Hock di na“, um dem aus dem Weg zu gehen.

@Phillip In meiner Gegend heißt's "der [d'r] Bank und das würde es auch in deinem Beispielsatz heißen. Vielleicht ist dein Dialekt schon mit Hochdeutsch "infiziert"?

@Philllip Ach dann.... :)

Der Akkusativ wird mit Verben der Bewegung verwendet. Heute interpretieren wir “setzen” als Bewegung.
Vergleiche das mit “sich hinlegen”: “Auf dieser/diese Bank will ich mich hinlegen” geht beides, weil “sich hinlegen” die Bewegung von stehen zu liegen oder die nicht-Bewegung “liegen” bedeuten kann.
Ähnlich: Ich tauche in dem / in den See.
